# Generate an array of several thousand random locations within such an array, e.g. (3,75) and (56,34) in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, random, coordinates

So far ive created 2 lists of data points labelled x and y respectively. I have no idea how to combine them into a single array though so that they are coordinates.

```
import random
import pylab

x = [(random.randint(0,100)) for i in range(3000)]
y = [(random.randint(0,100)) for j in range(3000)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine them with `zip()`:

```
zip(x, y)
```

or you can generate the numbers *together* to start with:

```
[(random.randint(0,100), random.randint(0,100)) for i in xrange(3000)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you're importing [`pylab`](http://www.scipy.org/PyLab). If you are happy to use a [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) array for the coordinates, you could simply write:

```
import numpy.random
coord = numpy.random.randint(0, 100, (3000, 2))
```

No need for explicit loops or list comprehensions. This makes the code ~120 times faster than a pure Python version:

```
In [6]: %timeit coord = numpy.random.randint(0, 100, (3000, 2))
10000 loops, best of 3: 82.7 us per loop

In [7]: %timeit coord = [(random.randint(0,100), random.randint(0,100)) for i in xrange(3000)]
100 loops, best of 3: 10.3 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> x = [(random.randint(0,100)) for i in range(3000)]
>>> y = [(random.randint(0,100)) for j in range(3000)]
>>> coords = zip(x,y)
>>> len(coords)
3000
>>> type(coords[0])
<type 'tuple'>
>>> coords[0]
(54, 0)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the lists as tuples to a new list containing the coordinates:

```
import random
import pylab

XY=[]

x = [(random.randint(0,100)) for i in range(3000)]
y = [(random.randint(0,100)) for j in range(3000)]

for xg, yg in zip(x,y):
    XY.append((xg,yg))
```

Comment: Why loop over the `zip()`? In Python 2, that is *already* a list, and you could call `list()` on the `zip()` result in Python 3.